# ThreadPool and GUI wait question

Tags: c#, threadpool, deadlock

I am new to threads and in need of help.  I have a data entry app that takes an exorbitant amount of time to insert a new record(i.e 50-75 seconds).  So my solution was to send an insert statement out via a ThreadPool and allow the user to begin entering the data for the record while that insert which returns a new record ID while that insert is running.  My problem is that a user can hit save before the new ID is returned from that insert.

I tried putting in a Boolean variable which get set to true via an event from that thread when it is safe to save.  I then put in

```
while (safeToSave == false)  
{  
    Thread.Sleep(200)  
}
```

I think that is a bad idea.  If i run the save method before that tread returns, it gets stuck.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a better way of doing this?
2. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for any help.
Doug

**Edit for more information:**

It is doing an insert into a very large (approaching max size) FoxPro database.  The file has about 200 fields and almost as many indexes on it.
And before you ask, no I cannot change the structure of it as it was here before I was and there is a ton of legacy code hitting it.  The first problem is, in order to get a new ID I must first find the max(id) in the table then increment and checksum it.  That takes about 45 seconds.  Then the first insert is simply and insert of that new id and an enterdate field.  This table is not/ cannot be put into a DBC so that rules out auto-generating ids and the like.

**@joshua.ewer**
You have the proccess correct and I think for the short term I will just disable the save button, but I will be looking into your idea of passing it into a queue.  Do you have any references to MSMQ that I should take a look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone else, including you, addressed the core problems (insert time, why you're doing an insert, then update), so I'll stick with just the technical concerns with your proposed solution.  So, if I get the flow right:

- Thread 1: Start data entry for
  record
- Thread 2: Background calls to DB to  retrieve new Id
- The save button is always enabled,
  if user tries to save before Thread
  2 completes, you put #1 to sleep for
  200 ms?

The simplest, not best, answer is to just have the button disabled, and have that thread make a [callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waitcallback.aspx) to a delegate that enables the button.  They can't start the update operation until you're sure things are set up appropriately.

Though, I think a much better solution (though it might be overblown if you're just building a Q&D front end to FoxPro), would be to throw those save operations into a queue.  The user can key as quickly as possible, then the requests are put into something like MSMQ and they can complete in their own time asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

1) Many :), for example you could disable the "save" button while the thread is inserting the object, or you can setup a Thread Worker which handle a queue of "save requests" (but I think the problem here is that the user wants to modify the newly created record, so disabling the button maybe it's better)

2) I think we need some more code to be able to understand... (or maybe is a synchronization issue, I am not a bug fan of threads too)

btw, I just don't understand why an insert should take so long..I think that you should check that code first! <- just as charles stated before (sorry, dind't read the post) :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [future](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/01/02/Its-the-future-now.aspx) rather than a raw ThreadPool action. Execute the future, allow the user to do whatever they want, when they hit Save on the 2nd record, request the value from the future. If the 1st insert finished already, you'll get the ID right away and the 2nd insert will be allowed to kick off. If you are still waiting on the 1st operation, the future will block until it is available, and then the 2nd operation can execute.

You're not saving any time unless the user is slower than the operation.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably find out, and fix, the reason why an insert is taking so long... 50-75 seconds is unreasonable for any modern database for a single row insert, and indicates that something else needs to be addressed, like indices, or blocking...

Secondly,  why are you inserting the record before you have the data?  Normally, data entry apps are coded so that the insert is not attempted until all the necessary data for the insert has been gathered from the user.  Are you doing this because you are trying to get the new Id back from the database first, and then "update" the new empty record with the user-entered data later?  If so, almost every database vendor has a mechanism where you can do the insert only once, without knowing the new ID, and have the database return the new ID as well... What vendor database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Is a solution like this possible:

Pre-calculate the unique IDs before a user even starts to add.  Keep a list of unique Id's that are already in the table but are effectively place holders.  When a user is trying to insert, reserve them one of the unique IDs, when the user presses save, they now replace the place-holder with their data.

PS:  It's difficult to confirm this, but be aware of the following concurrency issue with what you are proposing (with or without threads):  User A, starts to add, user B starts to add,  user A calculates ID 1234 as the max free ID,  user B calculates ID 1234 as the max free ID.  User A inserts ID 1234, User B inserts ID 1234 = Boom!

Comment: Yeah I thought about that as well, however the legacy code that hits this file also adds new records periodically.